# How do I reference a regression model's coefficient's standard errors?

Tags: r, regression-coefficients

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.2758     0.5185  19.817  < 2e-16 ***
rprice2      -1.8581     0.5139  -3.616 0.000696 ***
```

I would like to use the Std. Error of rprice2 to make other calculations. I know to reference any of the objects in the model, I use the syntax model$object, but what is the syntax for referencing the std errors?

Comment: what kind of model object is this? If your model object (call it mod) is a lm or a glm, you can extract the standard errors with summary(mod)$coef[,2]

Comment: it's an lm model, i'm trying to calculate the t-statistic with the following code, using your comment: tstat<-abs(model$coef/summary(model)$coef[2,2])...  which seems to work, but i'm not sure how to interpret the output of tstat which is: (Intercept)     rprice2 
   19.99568     3.61563

Comment: Note that the coefficients attribute (a 2x4 array) of the `summary()` output can be extracted using the `coef()` command. If you just want the estimated standard error for the coefficient of `rprice2`, use e.g. `coef(summary(mod))[2,2]`. If you want the corresponding t-statistic, use `coef(summary(mod))[2,3]`.

Answer (score 12):

Quite generally you want the `vcov` function which provides the complete parameter covariance matrix.  To get the regular asymptotic standard errors reported by `summary` you can use

```
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(model)))
```

btw you would want the off-diagonals of `vcov(model)` to get marginal effects for interaction terms: see [Brambor et al. (2006)](https://files.nyu.edu/mrg217/public/pa_final.pdf).

Note also packages like [sandwich](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/) devoted to constructing different types of standard errors, e.g. ones 'robust' to various types of violations.

Answer (score 5):

To extract without performing any other calculations, while using the object$model syntax:

```
summary(model)$coefficients["rprice2","Std. Error"]
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it you want to do this in R:

```
f <- lm(speed~dist, data=cars)
coef(f)
confint(f)
sd = sqrt(diag(vcov(f)))
cbind("2.5 %"=-sd*1.96+coef(f),"97.5 %"=sd*1.96+coef(f))
```

Gives:

```
> coef(f)
(Intercept)        dist 
  8.2839056   0.1655676 
> confint(f)
                2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 6.5258378 10.0419735
dist        0.1303926  0.2007426
> cbind("2.5 %"=-sd*1.96+coef(f),"97.5 %"=sd*1.96+coef(f))
                2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 6.5701120 9.9976992
dist        0.1312784 0.1998568
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't spot your own `vcov` application nestled in the middle of the code before I wrote my answer.

Comment: @ConjugatePrior: That's Ok. Obviously my answer was a little unclear and your comments on the subject added more body to the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

To obtain a matrix with the results of the linear regression:

```
> coef(summary(f))
```

To extract a specific value from the matrix:

```
> coef(summary(f))["rprice2","Std. Error"]
[1] 0.5139
```